# RLMResults change notification from change in RLMLinkingObjects

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have an RLMResults query that is queries partially based on a RLMLinkingObjects property.  The query returns objects where the date field on the linked object is nil. Something like this:

```
Linked.objectsWhere("NONE SELF.linked.date != nil")
```

When I set the date property to a non-null value, I do not get a callback in my results.addNotificationBlock({...}).  I would expect this block to be called indicating that my results set has changed.

What is the expected behavior when querying based on an RLMLinkingObjects property?

**EDIT:**

```
class Status: RLMObject {
    dynamic var statusId: String?
    dynamic var party: Party?
    dynamic var date: NSDate?
    dynamic var name: String
}
class Party: RLMObject {
    dynamic var partyId: String?
    dynamic var statuses: RLMLinkingObjects?

    class func query() -> RLMResults {
         return Party.objectsWhere("statuses.@count == 0 OR NONE statuses.date != nil")
    }

    override class func linkingObjectsProperties() -> [String : RLMPropertyDescriptor] {
        return ["statuses": RLMPropertyDescriptor(withClass: Status.self, propertyName: "party")]
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: Can you please share the definitions of the model classes involved in your query?

Comment: @bdash - I added the basic definitions in the post

Comment: This looks to be a bug. Would you mind filing a report over on [Realm Cocoa's GitHub repository](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/new)?

Comment: Hey @bdash - sorry I was out of town and haven't had much access to the internet, so never filed a report  However, I notice in the 1.0.2 release notes that this seems to be fixed.  I will confirm on my end when I am able to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to [an issue in Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3853) that was fixed in our v1.0.2 release earlier this week. If you're still seeing issues after updating to v1.0.2, please do go ahead and file an issue on GitHub so we can investigate the problem.